# Как получить результат переменной из другого потока

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Потоки создаются при подключении нового пользователя. В потоке выполняются различные функции, а также записываются логин и айпи откуда он зашел. Как мне можно узнать, например, переменную ip с другого потока?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо передать ссылку на тот поток, из которого вы хотите получать данные, в тот, в котором вы хотите эти данные обрабатывать.
После чего вы сможете вызывать публичные методы и получать доступ к публичным переменным. Пример:
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();
        DataConsumer dataConsumer = new DataConsumer(dataProvider);
        executor.execute(dataProvider);
        executor.execute(dataConsumer);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }


}


class DataProvider implements Runnable {

    private String userId;

    public synchronized String getLogin() {
        return userId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
            userId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }
    }
}


class DataConsumer implements Runnable {
    private DataProvider dataProvider;

    public DataConsumer(DataProvider dataProvider) {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
            System.out.println(dataProvider.getLogin());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут у вас все выводится через цикл. А как мне взять не все элементы, а например, 3 элемент?

Answer (score 0):

Напишите в потоке синхронизированный метод через который будете получать доступ к переменным потока:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private String ipAddress;

    public void run() {  //тело потока
       //blah-blah
    }

    public synchronized String getIpAddress() {
       return ipAddress;
    }

}
```

Comment: Я бы не наследовался от Thread, а имплементировал Runnable. Мне кажется, это правильнее.

Comment: Да в общем то нет принципиальной разницы, имплементация `Runnable` обычно удобнее только в одном, тем, что позволяет не разрушать существующую иерархию классов